# Need a postfix recipient-restriction to override a sender-/client-restriction

Tags: postfix

Our relay servers running postfix are configured to block NDRs by default - unless from listed IP addresses.

This is done by having smptd_sender_restrictions with check_client_access (with the IP database of 'xx.xx.xx.xx OK') and then check_sender_access (with a database including '<> REJECT')

We have a client on a dynamic IP who needs to send NDRs (i.e. From <>) to a specific email address...

Question: where in postfix can I put a 'check_recipient_xxxxx' type check that will allow an 'OK' status and short-circuit the rest of the sender/client-restrictions?

Any ideas?

Comment: "where in postfix can I put a 'check_recipient_xxxxx' type check that will allow an 'OK' status" by which criteria?

Comment: By the destination address.

The email I need to permit has a sender of '<>' and a recipient of 'stats@vista.sophos.com' - so it gets stomped by the sender_access restrictions before I can 'OK' it using the recipient_access restrictions...

I would normally allow it through by specifying source IP - but it's coming from a dynamic address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly it should be something like the following

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = restriction_class1
restriction_class1 = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_recipient_access, reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  
 check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_sender_access  
 permit_mynetworks  
 permit_sasl_authenticated

/etc/postfix/check_sender_access
<> restriction_class1

/etc/postfix/check_recipient_access
stats@vista.sophos.com OK
```

Comment: Cool - didn't know about the `smtpd_restriction_classes` bit - and have also found http://www.arschkrebs.de/postfix/postfix_restriction_classes.shtml which has more info. Thanks for the info!! :)